# Preselect drop down list when a value selected in sugarCRM

Tags: drop-down-menu, sugarcrm

I have two drop down lists, lets say: "Job Types" and "Person in charge".

When users choose a "Job type" it will preselect the "Person in charge".

Example:

## Job Types:

1. Finance
2. Computer
3. Sundry

## Person in charge:

1. Alice
2. Bob
3. Celion
4. David
5. Eason

When i choose "Finance", "David" will be pre-selected.
When i choose "Computer", "Celion" will be pre-selected.
...

How to customize this in SugarCRM? in Logic hook? or metadata?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to SugarCRM Professional's Sugar Logic, you might start here: http://www.profilingsolutions.com/archive/dropdowns-using-sugarlogic-formul/

This article uses a logic statement like `related($accounts,"account_type")` but you could write out a series of equal/if/then statements to check fieldA for various values.

More on Sugar Logic: http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/01_Sugar_Editions/04_Sugar_Professional/Sugar_Professional_6.7/Administration_Guide/07_Developer_Tools/01_Studio#Using_Sugar_Logic

If you are using SugarCRM CE, you won't have access to Sugar Logic. In that case, I find the easiest thing to do is adjust the module's editviewdefs to include custom JavaScript that monitors the field(s) and sets the values. Check `/modules/Notes/metadata/editviewdefs.php` for an example on including JavaScript in your edit view metadata.

One more caveat: if you were to use Sugar via it's API, it will ignore any thing you do to the UI view. You'll need to do this within a Logic Hook as well to enforce it throughout the system.